# All Conversions leaking into Conversions (Include in "conversions" unchecked)

Tags: google-ads-api

Wondering how it's possible for "all conversions" to leak into "conversions" when the include in "conversions" option is unchecked/no.

For example, the bottom 4 rows are all not supposed to be included in conversions. Only the first row is supposed to be included in conversions, which it is, 100%.

Is this a technical issue or something I am missing in the definitions?

[image: Conversions]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was in the process of the switch. Hence why there's some in conversions.